# Active Directory Migration from 2003 to 2012: authentications from 2012, 02 works

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2003

We have a SBS with one 2003 server for AD. Migration to 2012 went fine. Followed the instructions [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2014/04/01/step-by-step-active-directory-migration-from-windows-server-2003-to-windows-server-2012-r2/),
(just for info purposes)
but did not yet demote `dcpromo` on the 2003 server. We are still running fileshare on it as well so need to keep it running for now.  And after doing all these steps, when the 2003 server rebooted, I noticed 2012 ins't allowing anyone to log in. Any client machine enters credentials and the login window just spins without error. As long as DC2003 is up, everything is good, but dns is configured right on both machines, and i am getting ips from dc2003, just nothing is authenticating with 2012. I looked further,
I checked dhcp and it was not running on 2003 server, it was on a separate 2008 server, and that was still going. So i removed DHCP role from 2012.
but that shouldn't be stopping anyone from logging in when dc2003 is down right? I cant test until much later next week, so im looking for any insight/possibilities anyone can advise on.

## only dc2003 providing authentication after migration to 2012

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought - have you made sure that the DHCP option for DNS is pointing to DC2012? 
DNS option should be pointing to new server and also clients network stack reset (reboot computer?)